# Event ID: 4101 "Display driver nvlddmkm stopped responding and has successfully recovered." Faulty GPU or PSU?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, power-supply, crash, gpu

Before RMAing my card, I wanted to make sure that this isn't a PSU related issue.

I have a GTX 1080 (stock) that began crashing very often when running intensive games and software. This recently started happening about 1-2 days ago. Before that, everything ran fine.

I uninstalled the drivers using DDU, reseated the GPU, made sure my power settings were set at **"Prefer Maximum Performance"** in Nvidia Control Panel and **"High Performance"** set in Power Options, and even tried the TdrDelay in regedit.

I never OC'd my card and used it stock out the box but I even tried to up the wattage and lowered both clocks by 50Mhz using MSI AfterBurner. Running Heaven Benchmark, I am unable to get passed the first scene because it crashes at the same frame every time I tried. (Crashes not only happen during Benchmark but in games like GTA-V, The Witcher, etc) Usually in 5-10 minutes, sometimes even earlier.

I decided to plug in an old GTX 550Ti to test and ran through the whole benchmark just fine without crashes using the exact same settings as was on my 1080.

Is this because I had a faulty GPU or did the PSU not have enough juice to power the 1080?

I have Windows 10 Pro 64bit Version 1803 (Build 17134.137) , running the latest 398.36 drivers.

Comment: What driver version do you have installed?  What build of Windows 10 do you have installed?  Please add this vital required information to the body of your question.  If this is a new problem then it isn't a PSU issue.  While it could be a hardware problem, it's more likely, the problem is a driver problem.  **windbg** can confirm that fact though.

Comment: You tried a new card and it didn't crash, but go ahead and using the GTX 1080 with a different PCIe slot and see what happens. This has worked for quite a few people because it's a tricky thing to think of/figure out. In this case I'm not sure if it will improve anything.

Comment: I went ahead and RMA'd the card after trying a different PCIe slot and changing the slot that the GPU was seated on. Both still crashed. Then I tried using the HD Integerated 520 Graphics that was built into my mobo, it didn't crash. I think it's safe to say it was a faulty GPU since both the 550Ti and the Integrated didn't crash using the exact same settings in the benchmark.

I was a bit worried it was a faulty PSU not supplying enough power to the 1080 but I was wrong. Thank you for your help!